# Embedding a CMS in a Django app

Tags: django, django-cms

How would one go about this? I've done this previously with RoR using BrowserCMS, but how would I even go about doing something like this transparently on a django based site/app?

The idea is to be able to allow users to publish their own pages for their data, but then that data could be pulled for the app's purpose.  Not too difficult really, its the CMS part that has me scratching my head.

Any links? Blogs? Gits? Hints?  All appreciated.

TIA

Comment: I can't begin to understand where your problem is. If you want a Django CMS, just look at one of [the many fine packages](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/cms/) available.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sorry I wasn't clearer in phrasing my question.  What I meant is if I had a Django framework app, independent of the CMS, but wanted to include the CMS for certain sections of the site, like the user's own pages hosted on the app or the help pages, how would I go about embedding the CMS in the independent app?

Comment: Django-CMS will do what you're asking.

Comment: @Brandon How?  That's the crux of my question :)

Comment: DjangoCMS isn't "embedded" in a project - it is the basis of the project. It provides your navigational hierarchy, editable regions of pages, etc, etc, etc. Head over to http://django-cms.org/, run through their installation instructions and give it a spin.

Comment: @Brandon I did, just last night.  It looks pretty prolific, a bit of work needs to be done on the installation/set up side of things,IMHO, but nothing crazy.  I _think_ that what I'm looking for is something called "App Hooks".  Would you know of any resources on that?

Comment: Application hooks in Django-CMS are very simple. They provide a way to "hook" views that you write to a page provided by Django-CMS. That's how you could add a form, or pull in other models, respond to posts, etc...pretty much anything you could want to do with a web page.

Comment: That seems like what I need.  You wouldn't know of any resources I could read up on for hooks, would you?  Incidentally, nice portfolio you got there, kudos man.

Comment: Thank you very much. Django-CMS has pretty good documentation, but there aren't any books specifically on that topic. The way to think of hooks are really just pointers for pages to your own views. From there, your code will take over and you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Django-CMS](http://django-cms.org/) is absolutely awesome. It is the base application for 99% of what I build in my freelance business. You'll be hard pressed to find a CMS that is easier to extend or work with than Django-CMS.